How to use updateMany() with Node.js async method?
I have problem to use updateMany() in my node.js App, I got "Failed to update documents" Error. I could not find out the problem. Please help fix the code below:
router.get("/list_desc/:phone/Updatemany", isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const filter = {
      Phone_Number: req.params.phone,
      remark: "",
      transact_amount: {
        $gte: 0
      },
      tran_status: {
        $nin: ["Approved", "Paid"]
      },
      wired_amount: 0,
    };

    const update = {
      $set: {
        tran_status: "Approved",
        remark: "Left sm",
      },
    };

    const result = await Transact.updateMany(filter, update);

    if (result.ok) {
      res.redirect("/transact/list_desc_50");
    } else {
      throw new Error("Failed to update documents.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    // return res.status(500).send("An error occurred while updating documents.");
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});


What is the output of console.log(result)?

const result = await Transact.updateMany(filter, update);
console.log(result);
if (result.acknowledged) {
res.redirect("/transact/list_desc_50");
} else {
the console.log (result)    is { n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }

The Mongoose UpdateResult has 5 properties:
acknowledged
matchedCount
modifiedCount
upsertedCount
upsertedId

But no ok, thus if (result.ok)  will always take the else path in your code.
Use result.acknowldeged instead.

if (result.acknowledged)   ... YES now it is working and  no more error message.

Another thought on this:  if no documents match the filter, acknowledged will be true but matchedCount and modifiedCount will both be 0.  If that is not a successful condition for you, consider checking those values as well.
